# Mongoose/Mongo and Saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to figure out why the database won't update its documents, here is the code I have written trying to update these documents:

```
    if(didChange == true || didChange2 == true) {
      Report.find({}, function(err, report) {
        report.forEach(function (rep) {

           if(String(rep.author[0]) == String(id)) {
            console.log("IF HIT");
            rep.authors[0] = req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName;
            rep.save(function(err) {
              if (!err) {
                console.log("Success");
              }
              else {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
            console.log(rep);
           }
           tracker = tracker+1;
           if(tracker == report.length){
            console.log(tracker);
            console.log("finish");
            res.json(req.body);
           }
        });
          });

    }
    else {
    console.log("Hit");
    res.end();
  }
```

From the console it is showing that the authors field is the new values, however it is not saving. When looking at the db from the db commandshell, none of the values are actually updated. I'm kind of stuck on where to go. I'm sure it has something to do with async and how I wrote it or updating multiple documents accordingly.

Console output:

```
ID: 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3
IF HIT
{ _id: 55ba25e303be4c4c0edcd617,
  body: 'jajjajajaja',
  owner: 55ae608c5562285c11af5ad4,
  date: 'Thu Jul 30 2015 09:25:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'subs sub',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55ba1f4226945e8014f0fcdf,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55ba27b6403852900eec3ee5,
  body: 'asdadsa',
  owner: 55ae608c5562285c11af5ad4,
  date: 'Thu Jul 30 2015 09:33:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'for u deff',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55ba1f4226945e8014f0fcdf,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55ba283d403852900eec3ee6,
  body: 'adre',
  owner: 55ae608c5562285c11af5ad4,
  date: 'Thu Jul 30 2015 09:35:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'da',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55ba1f4226945e8014f0fcdf,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55ba2c140d63028c14810706,
  body: 'Enter subreport here',
  owner: 55ae608c5562285c11af5ad4,
  date: 'Thu Jul 30 2015 09:52:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'tstststst',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55ba1f4226945e8014f0fcdf,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55ba2c250d63028c14810707,
  body: 'ajjajaj',
  owner: 55ae608c5562285c11af5ad4,
  date: 'Thu Jul 30 2015 09:52:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'jajajajaj',
  __v: 1,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55bfc2784bb0ce6c1b41bdb2,
  body: '1231321',
  owner: 55bf60ccf5b98cd404e39eca,
  date: 'Mon Aug 03 2015 15:35:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'depth4',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55bfc1a533c03294168cf07f,
  isCompleted: true,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55c9f8d8e87a23080470e8b7,
  body: 'fefefeport here',
  owner: 55c9f80cd951be3c129f9a9f,
  date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  title: 'ffffefefe',
  __v: 1,
  parentReport: 55c9f8bee87a23080470e8b6,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
IF HIT
{ _id: 55c9fe5ae9be72d0196f458f,
  owner: 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3,
  title: 'fafafaf',
  date: 'Tue Aug 11 2015 09:53:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  body: 'afafafafaf',
  __v: 0,
  isCompleted: false,
  subreport: [],
  authors: [ 'deff feed' ],
  author: [ 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3 ] }
67
finish
Success
Success
Success
Success
Success
Success
Success
Success
```

Mongoose Debug:

```
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }) { unique: true, background: true, safe
: undefined }
Succeeded and connected to: mongodb://localhost/UserReports
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
undefined
Map {}
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
Warning: No route matches path "/assets/styles/public/assets/sass.map". Make sur
e you have <Route path="/assets/styles/public/assets/sass.map"> somewhere in you
r routes
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { fields:
 undefined }
Mongoose: reports.find({}) { fields: undefined }
ID: 55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("55ad14d0c2419660021d80b3") }) { '$set':
{ 'profile.firstName': 'deff' } }
```

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(rep)`?

Comment: Enable mongoose debugging and inspect the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, you use e.g. the [async modules "each" method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) to loop through your report array.

With this method you can loop through your reports one by one, and only take the next iteration, if e.g. a `save` callback has been finished.
This also makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Then, check out the [Mongoose Docs FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) (the first one):

> Mongoose doesn't create getters/setters for array indexes

So you should do

```
var newAuthorName = req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName
doc.authors.set(0, newAuthorName);
```

instead of

```
var newAuthorName = req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName
doc.authors[0] = newAuthorName;
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it a bit after you answered as well! As for the code, it was just a example and was a quick hack I was trying to figure out, was stumped on why it didnt work.